# How to use join() method in a class constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

I created a class syntax with properties and methods. 
Properties have arrays and I wanted to create space between those elements on the arrays. 
When I created a method that return a string with those properties ,I used join(', ') method to make space between the elements of the array.

When I create my instances and called them in the console it doesnt work. It gives this error :

```
*Uncaught TypeError: this.interests.join is not a function*
```

here is my code :

```
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first,
      last
    };

    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
  }


  greeting() {
    * //here is the problem *
    let hobbies = this.interests.join(' ,')
    return `Hi. I'm ${this.name.first} I am ${this.age} . I like ${hobbies}`;
  }

  farewell() {
    return `${this.name.first} has left the building. Bye for now!`;
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests, grade) {
    super(first, last, age, gender, interests);

    this.grade = grade;
  }
}

let ron = new Student('Ron', 'Weasley', 14, 'Quidditch', 3);
let harry = new Student('Harry', 'Potter', 14, ['Quidditch', 'cause problems'], 3);
let hermione = new Student('Hermione', 'Granger', 14, ['Studying', 'Read'], 3);
let neville = new Student('Neville', '', 14, 'Herbiology', 3);
```

Comment: this.interests is not guaranteed to have a value.

Comment: Your class definition defines interests as the 5th param, but you're passing it as the 4th param (and it's inconsistent in type - sometimes a string, sometimes an array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in some cases (`ron` and `neville`) the `interests` argument you are passing to your constructor isn't an array but a string.

Then, when you call the  `greeting` method later, the `join` method isn't present on strings hence the error.

You should transform the interests given in the constructor in an always-array with something like:

```js
this.interests = Array.isArray(interests) ? interests : [ interests ]
```

### Edit:

As Ivar suggest in the comment below, you are actually sending a number in place of the interests argument.

```
constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests)

//            ^      ^    ^      ^        ^
//            |      ++   +---+  +-----+  +----+
//            |       |       |        |       |

new Student('Ron', 'Weasley', 14, 'Quidditch', 3)
```

So, first, reorder your arguments when creating instances, then ensure they are always arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion . Still learning and your explanation is more than welcome

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems.

Firstly, your class constructor expects `interests` as the 5th param.

```
constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
```

However when instantiating you're passing it as the 4th param, e.g.

```
let harry = new Student('Harry', 'Potter', 14, ['Quidditch', 'cause problems'], 3);
```

Furthermore, your typing is inconsistent. `interests` (notwithstanding that it's passed to the wrong param) is usually passed as an array but sometimes as a string.

```
let ron = new Student('Ron', 'Weasley', 14, 'Quidditch', 3);
```

This will cause an error as strings obviously have no `.join()` method.